# How to vertically align two pgfplots in subfigures?

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats

I want to have two subfigures in a figure. Each subfigure contains a simple pgfplot.

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[a]{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, baseline]
            \begin{axis}[ybar]   
                \addplot+ coordinates { 
                    (1,2)
                };  
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, baseline]
            \begin{axis}[ybar]   
                \addplot+ coordinates { 
                    (1,2)
                };  
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the second image is higher than the first one... I want to have both images at the same height.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}` (Note the placement specifier `[t]`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
      \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, baseline]
            \begin{axis}[ybar]
                \addplot+ coordinates {
                    (1,2)
                };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
      \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, baseline]
            \begin{axis}[ybar]
                \addplot+ coordinates {
                    (1,2)
                };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Another figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh god... I was sure that this was the index of the subfigures (a), b), c), ...). Thanks.

Comment: beautifully indented code :) +1