# pgfplots and subcaption subfigures not aligned vertically

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I'm trying to create a figure with 3 figures horizontally. I'm using `figure*` environment, as I'm working in a two-column document, so that it spans the whole width horizontally. I'm using both `pgfplots` and the `subcaption` package.

However, as I create the three figures with equal width, the one in the middle appears a little below the others. Here is an image for reference:
[image: Example of the problem]

My code is the following:

```latex
\begin{figure*}[!t]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{figs/err_G_pert}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{figs/err_X_sparsity}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \input{figs/err_S_samp}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure*}
```

And in the inputted files there is only the creation of a tikzpicture as follows `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,scale=1]`. I've tried setting the width to 0.3 but no luck.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: Maybe, this post it help [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83043/how-to-vertically-align-two-pgfplots-in-subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83043/how-to-vertically-align-two-pgfplots-in-subfigures)

Comment: Actually, that was the solution. Not sure why it didn't appear in my search queries. Thank you very much for your comment. I'm going to add the answer.

Comment: If you want to align the captions, use [b] instead of [t].  If you want to align the pgfplot boxes, add `[baseline={(0,0)}]` in the tikzpictures.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alex mentioned in his comment, the solution was included in the following post [How to vertically align two pgfplots in subfigures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83043/how-to-vertically-align-two-pgfplots-in-subfigures).

I needed to specify the placement parameter [t] in my subfigures.